# How to avoid Observable calling multiple times RxDart

Tags: flutter, dart, observable, bloc, rxdart

I have implemented BLOC pattern to my login screen.

The code below is button click event here what happens is when i click the Login button with wrong credentials first time it shows snackbar once, if i click the button again it show two times if i again click it shows three times & so on...

```
Future _validateInputs() async {
    final form = _loginKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      print(_userIDController.text + _passwordController.text);
      bloc.validateLogin(_userIDController.text, _passwordController.text);
      bloc.loginDetails.listen((loginDetails){
        if(loginDetails != null) {
          if(loginDetails.loginStatus) {
            // Navigate to Home
            print("Login Sucess");
          } else {
            print(loginDetails.failureMessage);
            scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('Invalid Username or Password'),
            ));
            //bloc.clear();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This is my BLOC code i don't know where i'm doing wrong.

```
class LoginBloc {
  final _repository = Repository();
  var _doLogin = PublishSubject<LoginModel>();

  Observable<LoginModel> get loginDetails => _doLogin.stream;

  validateLogin(String userName,String password) async {
    LoginModel itemModel = await _repository.doLogin(userName,password);
    _doLogin.sink.add(itemModel);
  }


  dispose() {
    _doLogin.close();
  }
}

final bloc = LoginBloc();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are registering a listener (by calling `listen`) every time you call `_validateInputs`. You should listen once in the initState or try out the [`first`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/first.html) property from `Observable` which returns a Future.